# Method of characteristics $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} + 2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, factoring, characteristics

I know how to solve problems with form like this (via method of characteristics):
$$a(x,y) u_{x}+b(x,y)u_y=c(x,y).$$
But I got this problem: $$ \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} + 2\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}=0$$
with conditions: $$ u(0,y)=0, u(x,1)=x^2. $$

My idea was to factorize the equation and I get this:
$$ (\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial }{\partial y})(\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial }{\partial y})u=0. $$

Probably, I can get characteristic if I solve: $$(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y})=0.$$

I get that characteristic is: $y=x+c.$

But what now? How do I continue or is there a better way to solve this equation via method of characteristics?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ is not the same thing as $\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$

Comment: Note that $u(x,y):=x^2-y^2$ satisfies the differential equation (though not the given initial conditions), but does not satisfy
$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From

$$ \left(\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)\left(\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)u=0. $$

making

$$
U = \left(\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)u
$$

we have

$$
\left(\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)U=0
$$

gives

$$
U = \phi(y-x)
$$

and then solving

$$
\left(\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)u=\phi(y-x)
$$

we have

$$
u(x,y) = x\phi(y-x)+\psi(y-x)
$$

with the boundary conditions we have

$$
u(0,y) = 0\phi(y-0)+\psi(y-0)= \psi(y) = 0\\
u(x,1) = x\phi(1-x) = x^2
$$

or

$$
\phi(\eta) = 1-\eta
$$

and finally

$$
u(x,y) = x(1 - y + x)
$$